# Should language/frameworks be omitted or even removed from question titles?

Tags: discussion, title

In a question like *"How do I do X in C#?"* where `C#` is a clear tag, is it considered good or bad to duplicate it in the title?

I seem to recall in the early days it was certainly frowned upon but on the other hand when searching online "How do I do X in C#?", it (presumably) helps the search engine distinguish from "How do I do X in Java?"... or do tags get used by search engines too?

Basically:

1. Does anyone care either way if I put things like "C#" or ".Net" in my titles?
2. Does anyone care enough that editing titles to address 1 would be worthwhile? Or is it a waste of time?

Comment: I typically leave it, because I feel like it helps in searches for SEO reasons (without having SO searching)

Comment: The rule is to make the title a *proper sentence*. So, if you integrate the name of the language/framework into it organically, then that's fine. But don't just prepend or append the name to a title, because the system is already going to do that for SEO purposes. Besides, it looks bad and negatively impacts readability. See also: [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: @CodyGray sure but in my example both sentences are valid and the tags should make it clear to SO users. So is there _any_ official preference either way or is it to the asker's discretion?

Comment: Your example being, "How do I do X in C#"? Yes, this is fine. I'd say that's a good title. And if it's something you might want to do in *either* C# or Java, then adding the language to the title makes good sense, too, yes.